# Having trouble setting up a Redmi 2100 router

Tags: networking, router, setup, xiaomi

So, I bought a [Redmi 2100 router](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0PSUPdl2YJU), and I'm trying to set it up. I...

- Plugged it in.
- Waited for the main led to become blue.
- Connected its "Internet" RJ-45 socket to the fiber media adapter (using the same CAT 5e cable the old router was using).
- Made sure all of the fiber media adapter lights were on/blinking (like with the old router).

At this point my trouble (may have) started: The Internet LED remained orange, and has not turned blue.

Now I:

- Plugged in a CAT 5 cable from my PC.
- Pulled a DHCP lease from my PC, got 192.168.31.something .
- Connected to http://192.168.31.1
- Got this welcome screen:
  [image]

This was the second problem-point: I don't know what that says, and couldn't even copy the text to translate it later when I re-connect some other way. Still,

- Clicked the only available button (I assume I haven't said yes to running `rm -rf /` and signing my soul over to Xiaomi)
- Got a loading-circle-graphic, waited a bit
- Got this screen:

  [image]

... and that's where I got stuck. I believe I am connected the way the router expects me to be, but something is not to its liking and I don't know what. Help?

The unboxing and setup video I've found do not seem to address this (unless I've missed something).

Comment: So, apparently, on the first window, the first line is "I have read and agreed to the RedMi router User License Agreement", and the second line is "Has joined the User Experience Improvement Program". So, next time, deselect the second item before proceeding. The button reads "Experience it now".

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting does indeed correspond to the orange Internet indicator you see on the router. Here is the translation:
[image]